# Anyone problems with PDT 2.0 and Eclipse 3.4.2?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, ganymede

I just installed Eclipse 3.4.2 with PDT 2.0 and it seems that in PHP perspective I'm unable to see any files in the project. When I switch to J2EE view I can see all the files in the project just fine.

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: I should know this because I used PDT for a long time since Eclipse is so great for Java. But, while Eclipse is great for Java, for PHP Netbeans beats it into the ground. This is my personal, unsolicited opinion.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. However, that's no answer to my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your "Error Log" view is reporting ? (`Help > About > Configuration Details > View Error Log`)

(or what do you see in the `<workspace>/.metadata/.log` file)

There are [many issues reported with PDT2.0](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03464.html).
y be a PDT2.0.1 or one early [2.1 release](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03474.html) may already fix some problems, but this should be tested with an [early release of Galileo (3.5Mx)](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03480.html) instead of GanyMalede.

Answer (score 0):

PDT works like a charm with eclipse Galileo. I would STRONGLY recommend that you switch